# Disable Appcompact_v7 inclusion: Android

Tags: android, eclipse, actionbarsherlock

With the new ADT plugin, whenever I create a new Activity, it extends `ActionBarActivity` probably because of `app_compact_v7` library that is automatically added. Is it possible to disable this feature and still use the Support library in my project?  I know the need for backward compatibility but I prefer `ActionBarSherlock` library and not `AppCompact`. So is it possible to do away with automatic `app_compact_v7`inclusion in my project's?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't "do away with it", if you use the new-project or new-activity wizards. Near as I can tell, the templates there want you to use `appcompat-v7`, as of v22.6.1.

Your choices are:

- Stick with the new-project wizard and rip out the `appcompat-v7` stuff by hand, or
- Copy or import some other Eclipse project as a starting point, one that does not have `appcompat-v7` in it

Comment: Wow, this appcompact is certainly not good. Who suggested this to the ADT plugin developers? At least they should have known we have other backward compatibility libraries, besides Appcompact, before forcing Appcompact down our throat.

Comment: @nmvictor: I had missed the 22.6 release when it came out this month, and so I happen to be experimenting with it today, and I feel your pain. I had filed [an issue, requesting a project template sans junk](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=67513) shortly before I saw your question. FWIW, I'll be hosting blank projects for import in Eclipse [in the releases section of my book's samples GitHub repo](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/releases) (see `BlankProject.zip`). Eventually, hopefully, I won't need 'em anymore.

Comment: Thanks alot. I will make do with Blank projects for now but I hope ADT developers will have a better work around to this problem.

Comment: It seems that Google would rather you carry pre-version 4 compatibility... Only 20% of the global fleet is running on v2.x, the rest are on v4+ http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_version_history. I hope Google don't do an "IBM" and carry this baggage forever.

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem until I started creating the app I was taught in class.
Here is what I did to stop using appcompact_v7:

1. Started new Android Application Project
2. Named the project whatever you want
3. Changed Minimum Required SDK to **API 14: Android 4.0 (IceCreamSandwich)**
4. Left everything else default and you can press Finish or Next

That stopped the ADT from using appcompact_v7 for me at least.

Answer (score 1):

Continues answer of Nate, if you want add other API to you project Follow the next steps:

1. Started new Android Application Project
2. Named the project whatever you want
3. Changed Minimum Required SDK to API 14: Android 4.0 (IceCreamSandwich)
4. Left everything else default and you can press Finish or Next'
5. Change the AndroidManifest.xml with the API that you want